# Reading input from midi controller through javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, midi

i would like to attach html controls like textboxes to a midi controller, is there any way to achieve this through javascript/jquery?

Comment: I guess.... what do you have so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS has no concept of "hardware". Unless that midi controller has some kind of a web-based interface that you can point a URL at, or the controller can insert its data into a normal keyboard/mouse input stream, then no, you cannot use JS to talk to it at all.

Comment: There is actually a web api, called Web Midi Api - https://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code is generally untrusted, so runs in the web browser 'sandbox'. This means it can only interface with local hardware in a very limited way. In all browsers I know of interfacing with MIDI devices has not been exposed to the Javascript sandbox.

You can create a Java applet which interfaces with the MIDI device and then call the java applet from javascript. The java applet will probably have to be signed to allow it to interact with a MIDI device connected to the computer. This means it will prompt the user to trust it when it first runs.

Here is a code sample for recording from a MIDI device using Java: http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MidiInDump.html

Here is an intro on calling a Java applet from Javascript: http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php

One problem you'll also run into if the applet is signed is when you call a method from javascript that method will run with limited permissions. You will have to get a little familiar with the java security model to be able to run your code with elevated privileges in this case.